# steps to learn phonegap in right order

Tags: cordova, sdk

I just heard about phonegap that this is framework which let developers make web apps and then wrap with phonegap framework to build native apps. If that is correct, developers should first make web app (using HTML, JS, CSS), then work under phonegap and finally create builds to make native apps.

BUT when I visited its getting started page its say install SDK ( say Android ) in start. this should be the last step. First it should allow me to make web app and then let me decide for which plateform I want to make app.

Is there any way to learn phonegap without installing those SDKs like Android etc.

I just want to learn phonegap, its plateform independent then why I install android SDK as first step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you still need to compile your application with the native SDK even if you use PhoneGap. You could try using a cloud IDE like:

http://www.applaudcloud.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com) service as well. This service allows one to upload their HTML, JS and CSS and get back a installable binary for iOS, Android, BB, Windows Phone, webOS and Symbian.