# Phonegap Developer App : Do I need to install SDK android?

Tags: cordova

If I wish to use the phonegap developer app do I need to install the `SDKs` for individual platforms as well?

Comment: you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609127/steps-to-learn-phonegap-in-right-order/10612544#10612544

Answer (score 1):

### Answer is **NO**

The PhoneGap Developer App is an appstore deployed app. You install it through your devices native appstore (iOS, Android or Windows Phone). With only the Phonegap CLI installed on your development machine, and the PhoneGap Developer app installed on your mobile device, you can deploy your app to the device.

Note that you do **not** need:

1. Native SDK's, xcode, android bundle, etc
2. Developer account (iOS developer program membership, signing keys etc)

The PhoneGap Developer App bypasses these by providing an app shell, preloaded with the Cordova runtime environment, and core plugins.

Read more here: [app.phonegap.com](http://app.phonegap.com)

Comment: Well I have the CLI installed on my computer connected to my router via LAN. And the app is installed on my tab connected via Wi-Fi to the same router. Still it gives Timed-Out Error. Please Help. I followed the instructions given on app.phonegap.com and created the example app. Sorry for late response.